# Android "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_SEARCH" Not working

Tags: android, shell, keyboard, adb

I want to fire `KEYCODE_SEARCH` event using `ADB` in my code. When i execute this command i am unable to see any action in keyboard. But If i give `"adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_1"` it is working perfectly. Please give me any solution to fire search event using `ADB`.

And My current code is like.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});


<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `adb shell input keyevent 84` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_SEARCH

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for replay,  I tried this one also , but no use.

Comment: Did you add search widget or search dialog or searchable activity in your code?

Comment: No, This is just EditText I am adding android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The setting `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` doesn't enables your edit text to receive `KEYCODE_SEARCH` event.

As described on [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions):

> **android:imeOptions** 
>   Additional features you can enable in an IME associated with an editor
>   to improve the integration with your application. The constants here
>   correspond to those defined by imeOptions.

If you want to receive `KEYCODE_SEARCH` sent from ADB you need to override `onKeyDown` in your `Activity` and manually call `onEditorAction`

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){
        editText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);
        return true;
    }else{
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Please note that the other apps don't fire the search when `KEYCODE_SEARCH` event is sent, they simply give focus to the search box